# Find nearest number

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a problem using Javascript but couldn't find what's going wrong with my code:

Question:

> Given a list of words and two words word1 and word2, return the
> shortest distance between these two words in the list.

For example,

> Assume that words = ["practice", "makes", "perfect", "coding",
> "makes"].
>
> Given word1 = “coding”, word2 = “practice”, return 3.
>
> Given word1 = "makes", word2 = "coding", return 1.

**My solution:**

```
var shortestDistance = function(words, word1, word2) {
  
  var w1=-1, w2=-1, min;
  
  words.forEach(function(word, index){
    
    if(word == word1)
      w1 = index;
    if(word == word2)
      w2 = index;
     if (w1 != -1 && w2 != -1)
        min = Math.abs(w1-w2);
  });
  return min;
};
```

It works for the inputs specified above, but it fails for the following:

> shortestDistance(["a","a","b","b"], "a","b"); (outputs 2 instead of 1)

What am i missing?

Comment: Your function never compares distances to see if one is smaller than another. It just returns the distance between the last match of each word.

Comment: Maybe you should make use of the `min` variable that you declared?

Comment: Why  "coding" to "practice" is 3 but "makes" to "coding" is 1?

Comment: @Einsamer `coding` is at index `3` and `practice` is at `0`, so the distance is 3. `makes` is at `1` and `4`, so the distances are `2` and `1`, and `1` is the shorter distance.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot the last one. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you find a match for one of the words you need to calculate the distance, and then see if this is shorter than the minimum distance you previously found.

```js
var shortestDistance = function(words, word1, word2) {

  var w1 = words.indexOf(word1);
  var w2 = words.indexOf(word2);
  if (w1 == -1 || w2 == -1) {
    // one of the words isn't in the list
    return 0;
  }
  var min = Math.abs(w1 - w2);
  words.forEach(function(word, index) {
    var distance;
    if (index > w1 && word == word1) {
      w1 = index;
      distance = Math.abs(w1 - w2);
    } else if (index > w2 && word == word2) {
      w2 = index;
      distance = Math.abs(w1 - w2);
    }
    if (distance < min) {
      min = distance;
    }
  });
  return min;
};
console.log(shortestDistance(["a","a","b","b"], "a","b"));
```

Comment: I googled, the author mentioned this solution:

`https://jsfiddle.net/wop40228/`

I did not get Math.min part

Comment: Thank you for the comment and explanation. It's great to see different approaches!

Comment: `Math.min()` calculates the minimum of its arguments. So if `Math.abs(w1-w2)` is smaller than `min`, it sets `min` to that.

Comment: It's a way to do what I do with `if(distance < min)`, but it doesn't need a separate variable.

Comment: Why do you wish that? The other two answers are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

### What's happening?

- Iteration 1 (["**a**","a","b","b"]): `w1` is set to `0`
- Iteration 2 (["a","**a**","b","b"]): `w1` is set to `1`
- Iteration 3 (["a","a","**b**","b"]): `w2` is set to `2`

Here, we have found the correct values for `w1` and `w2`. However, your program doesn't know this, and keeps going:

- Iteration 4 (["a","a","b","**b**"]): `w2` is set to `3`

This is the cause of the problem with your code.

### What can we do?

Simply, we need to check each iteration if the distance between `w1` and `w2` is smaller than it was previously. Here's one way we could do that:

```
function shortestDistance(words, word1, word2) {
    var w1, w2;
    for (i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
        if (words[i] == word1) {
            w1 = i;
        }
        else if (words[i] == word2) {
            w2 = i;
        }
        if (w1!=null&&w2!=null) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return Math.abs(w1-w2);
}
```

This code is practically the same as your original code (I changed from a `foreach` because `break` doesn't work in that), but it exits the moment that a value for `w1` and `w2` has been found, thus ensuring that they are always the closest two instances of `w1` and `w2` in `words`.

This code will return the correct answer of `1` - https://jsfiddle.net/joy40459/4/

Comment: This won't return the correct answer for `makes` and `coding`. It returns as soon as it has found a match for both words, but it needs to keep looking to see if there are closer matches.

Comment: Why link to jsfiddle instead of using Stack Snippet to execute it here?

Comment: And in jsfiddle, why do you have the code in the html box, not the javascript box?

Comment: @Barmar The Javascript box wasn't working in Fiddle, so just put it in with HTML. I guess I just use jsfiddle out of old habits - I really should start using the built-in Stack Snippet instead. You do raise an extremely good point about `makes` and `coding`, too... didn't really think of that when writing my answer.

Comment: The JS box will work if you change "OnLoad" to "No wrap" in the Javascript popup. See https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/joy40459/3/

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I didn't know that. +1